# Cómo obtener la fecha empezando con el año y no con el día

Tags: javascript

Obtengo la fecha pero empezando por el día y la necesito obtener empezando con el año. Qué debería hacer?

```js
const hoy = new Date();;
document.write(hoy.toLocaleDateString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar de esta manera:

```js
var f = new Date();
document.write(f.getFullYear() + "/" + (f.getMonth() +1) + "/" + f.getDate());
```